# Is it possible to create object without declaring class?

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to create object without declaring class? Like in JavaScript 
`obj = {a: '1'}; console.log(obj.a)`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In Groovy you must always provide the class of an object being created, so there is no equivalent in Groovy to JavaScript's object-literal syntax.

However, Groovy does have a literal syntax for a `Map`, which is conceptually very similar to a JavaScript object, i.e. both are a collection of properties or name-value pairs.

The equivalent Groovy code to the JavaScript above is:

```
def obj = [a: '1']
println obj.a
```

Even though there is no class name used here you're still creating an object of a particular class (`java.util.LinkedHashMap`). The code above is just shorthand for:

```
def obj = new LinkedHashMap();
obj.a = '1'
println obj.a
```

The [`Expando` class](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ie/2009/10/groovy-goodness-expando-as-dynamic-bean.html) is perhaps even more similar to a JavaScript object, and is useful when you want to avoid the "overhead" of defining a class, or want a dynamic object to which any arbitrary property can be added at runtime.

Comment: you can also use this syntax to create an empty map:    def obj = [:]

Comment: Interesting. In case one you would wonder - it's allowed to use arrays/lists inside `LinkedHashMap`. E.g. this works: `def obj = [a: [1,2, "foo"]]; obj.a.push("bar")`

Answer (score 35):

Slightly surprised that nobody has mentioned the Expando class.  This adds extra functionality over a map in that you can directly reference properties within your functions.  Code example below.

```
def expando = new Expando(a:"def")
expando.run = {def b ->
println("$a")
println("$b")
}
expando.run("ABC")

def map = [a:"def"]
map.run = {def b ->
 println("$a") //THIS DOES NOT WORK.  You will get a missing property exception.
 println("$b")
}
map.run("ABC")
```

printed output:

def

ABC

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

ABC (if you comment out the println($a) in the map.run, println($b) prints out ABC)

Ignore the extra line breaks in the output.  Was having a heck of a time putting def and ABC on consecutive lines.

See the [Expando API documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Expando.html) for more information.

Comment: Great find! The illustrious Mr Haki has also written about the Expando class: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-expando-as-dynamic-bean.html

I would say that the Expando class is actually the answer to what was being asked.

Comment: Using expando is the correct answer. Using Maps as anonimous Objects is more a hack.

Comment: I've noticed that if you have a property "name", and use "$name" it will pick the top level's name property, likely the Class name, and not the Expando's name property.

Answer (score 6):

Groovy has an equivalent notation for json. Only difference is they use [:] for maps instead of {}. So you can clearly convert a json into a groovy object notation.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def obj = [:] //define map
obj.batsmen = [] //define array 
def b = [:] 
b.name= "V. Kohli"
b.score = 55
b.strike = false

obj.batsmen.push(b)

//push second object
obj.batsmen.push(b)
println JsonOutput.toJson(obj)
```

Here I have not printed the object directly. Since it will print with square braces notation.

Read the whole article. Groovy for javascript developers.
https://metamug.com/article/groovy-for-javascript-developers.php

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [literal map](https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_map_literals):

```
config = [
        host    : '0.0.0.0',
        user    : 'user1',
        password: 'pass'
]

println("""
HOST: ${config.host}
USER: ${config.user}
PASS: ${config.password}
""")
```

> You can also return a literal map as a function return value without having to define a custom class e.g. `return [status: 200, body: 'abcdef']` and then in the caller access the values e.g. with `response.status`.