Camunda 7 scripting - race conditions across process-instances while setting a variable
I am new to Camunda and I have a workflow with a sub-process that accesses parent variables.
Specifically, the parent does this in a script task (groovy code):
class Result {
    Boolean canProceed
    String errorMessage
}

Init();

def Init()
{
    def result = execution.hasVariable("result");
    if(result == false)
    {
        result = new Result();
//        execution.removeVariable("result");
        execution.setVariable("result", result);
    }
}

def setError(errorMessage)
{
    Init();
    def result = execution.getVariable("result");
    result.canProceed = false;
    result.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

def setSuccess()
{
    Init();
    def result = execution.getVariable("result");
    result.canProceed = true;
    result.errorMessage = null;
}

And the sub-process calls the setSuccess() and setError("sth") functions.
The workflow does not contain any user tasks, so once I start a process instance, it executes and it gets done/destroyed, after I get the result variables back.
All is working fine when I call the workflow once at a time.
But when I bombard it with parallel calls (each time creating a new process instance), then I get weird errors  revolving around variables.
This is the C# code that calls the workflow in parallel:
var camunda = CamundaClient.Create("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest");
var pd = camunda.ProcessDefinitions.ByKey("name");

var actionNames = new string[] {
    ...
    ...
    ...
};

var repetition = 0;
var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(actionNames, parallelOptions, async (actionName, ct) => {
    var result = await PerformAction(actionName: actionName);
});

async Task<Result> PerformAction(string actionName)
{
    var businessKey = $"temp-id:{Guid.NewGuid()}";

    var camundaResult = await pd.StartProcessInstance(new Camunda.Api.Client.ProcessDefinition.StartProcessInstance
    {
        BusinessKey = businessKey,
        Variables =
        {
            { "action", VariableValue.FromObject(new { name = actionName }) },
        },
        WithVariablesInReturn = true,
    });

    var processResultJson = camundaResult.Variables["result"]?.Value as string;
    var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Result>(processResultJson, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    return result;
}

When MaxDegreeOfParallelism is bigger than 1, I get all kinds of unexpected errors, like:

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.camunda.bpm.engine.ProcessEngineException: ENGINE-17004 Cannot add variable instance with name result. Variable already exists'
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.getParentActivityInstanceId()" because "scopeExecution" is null

Any idea why this happens and what I can do to fix it?
Update:
Here are some stack traces (they were too long to post here):
https://mega.nz/file/cR0VSLDA#W1f_a4Xxs6OI0hREfAc1SBwx0nzvDrQb3Jn1qPDoGpE
And here is the workflow file:
https://mega.nz/file/NM1kDDxK#zsiqoi-7meHYLV4cYl7Qa9CAmQdtyFAW3aMf4cNAKA0

i don't see any reason to declare class Result. why not to reserve 2 plain variables like resultCanProceed and resultError. and avoid all this extra logic if hasVariable. for errors it's better to provide stacktrace.

@daggett I have added some stack traces from Camunda. Using plain variables will only hide the null reference problem, as far as I understand. If I cannot be certain that variables get set correctly on the scope, I have a problem to begin with.

IMHO: declaring class in a script is bad idea - you could have different class declaration versions for different calls. Just remove class, simplify code, and focus on real error if any remains.

@daggett I have replaced the class with a LinkedHashMap by replacing all the new Result() with [canProceed: false, errorMessage: errorMessage];, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312921/2173353 . I still get the same problem. I could potentially try to minimize the cases/places where I set the variables, but this will only make the problem a bit more rare, not eliminate it.

please show how sub-process calls the setSuccess() and setError("sth") functions.

@daggett I have added the workflow file.

It's wired that it's somehow working. I would recommend it again - reserve 2 variables for status and error, remove all function declarations, and call only execution.setVariable(...). if you want to have class, methods for status - create usual java/groovy class (outside of camunda workflow), compile it, and add it into a classpath of camunda. don't declare any classes/functions  inside the workflow.

@daggett I've already tried using a LinkedHashMap, as I've mentioned above, and it didn't help. I've shared an old version of the workflow that uses a class because the workflow file has evolved since I posted the question and I would need to adjust a lot of things. You can try using a LinkedHashMap to see for yourself. The problem is not the data-type that holds the data, but some concurrency issue inside the Camunda engine. Which is weird, because I thought that each process instance was isolated from other process instances. Isn't the variable scope limited to a single process instance?
